# AForge - Working with video card with multiple cameras

Tags: c#, video, camera, aforge

I can get AForge to work with an USB web cam, but I have a video card that can connect to multiple cameras. How do I get AForge to work with the video card?

My issue is I could not get the `VideoInputDevice` to set to a working video input.

The code is like this:

```
void init(){
    FilterInfoCollection videoCaptureDevice =
        new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    VideoCaptureDevice finalVideo =
        new VideoCaptureDevice(videoCaptureDevice[0].MonikerString);

    finalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(finalVideo_NewFrame);

    finalVideo.Start();
}

public void finalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    pictureBox1.Image = temp;

}
```

I also tried:

```
finalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice();
finalVideo.CrossbarVideoInput = VideoInput.Default;
```

and it did not work either.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in your code

`VideoCaptureDevice finalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoCaptureDevice[0].MonikerString);`

registers the first device [0]
i asume if you would put in [1] there you get the second device.

also note this line

```
  finalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(finalVideo_NewFrame);
```

there you define what event name (finalvide_Newframe) should trigger when there is a new image frame received for that specific camera. Most simple would be to register two different events. So each camera [0] and [1] receives its own event to display it.

here some additional code hints that might be helpfull for you its what i use to select a camera, its just an idea for if you have multiple external camera's (make 2 combo boxes) but dont want to use for example a laptops internal cam.

```
VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

            foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
            } // to get all your devices inside a combo box;
```

with that you could do

```
 FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
```

Comment: Sorry to say this would not work because the videoCaptureDevice is null. It did not see any video input.

Comment: hm thats odd 
you also wrote that you can get it to work with an usb video camera.
so it is the capture card that gives you problems.
Did you took a look inside his code, its full of comments that might be usefully to your specific environment.
take a look here 
http://aforge.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1680/trunk/Sources/Video.DirectShow/VideoCaptureDevice.cs

Answer (score 0):

look in the aforge examples when you download the whole package, there is a demo snapshotmaker, that works with multiple camera's.