# How To Get A List Of Available Video Capture Devices

Tags: c#, c++, .net, directshow, directshow.net

I am creating a project using DirectShow.Net that shows a preview of a webcam view within a windows form using Visual C#.

I would like to start with gaining a collection of available video devices so I can choose between either the built in webcam or the USB webcam.

I have seen several examples of this being done in C++, e.g. on the msdn "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377566(v=vs.85).aspx".

However as I do not know any C++ I do not know how to convert this code into C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DirectShow.NET sample `\Samples\Capture\DxLogo\Capture.cs` shows how to do it:

```
// Get the collection of video devices
capDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
```

The keyword you need is `FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice`.

See also:

- [Is directshow.net video input device filter enumeration broken (in newer environments)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657873/is-directshow-net-video-input-device-filter-enumeration-broken-in-newer-environ)
- [AForge - Working with video card with multiple cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297577/aforge-working-with-video-card-with-multiple-cameras/13615996#13615996)

Answer (score 6):

.netcore solution:
Install the package: [**DirectShowLib.Standard**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DirectShowLib.Standard)

Then you can get the cameras list:

```
var devices = new List<DsDevice>(DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice));
var cameraNames = new List<string>();
foreach (var device in devices)
{
    cameraNames.Add(device.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The often suggested approaches of requesting the Windows Media Foundation or Directshow API were not sufficient to me. But fortunately I have found this [solution by Michaël Hompus](https://blog.hompus.nl/2021/01/04/using-the-opencv-videocapture-class-with-the-name-of-a-camera/). The usage is as simple as follows:

```
using var sde = new Hompus.VideoInputDevices.SystemDeviceEnumerator();

foreach (var device in sde.ListVideoInputDevice())
{
    yield return new Webcam
    {
        Name = device.Value,
        Index = device.Key,
    };
}
```

The respective GitHub repository can be found [here](https://github.com/eNeRGy164/VideoInputDevices).