# Automatically open the rear camera on a windows 8 tablet using EasyWebCam in c#

Tags: c#

I'm currently putting together a little project in c# designed to be used on Windows based tablets.

I have integrated the open source code available from http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/ to run the tablets camera. However, when you click the start button, it asks you to choose between the front or rear camera and as it is being used on a touch screen tablet, it's a bit on the fiddly side.

Does anyone know of a way of either adding a button to choose between the cameras or, better still, a way of automatically selecting the rear camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows Store apps, a list of video capture device ids can be returned from [DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225436.aspx)(DeviceClass.VideoCapture). See the [Device enumeration sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Device-Enumeration-Sample-a6e45169) for details.

Then you can [set MediaCaptureInitializationSettings.VideoDeviceId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452791.aspx) and use it to initialize a capture session. Note however, this only supports UI-less capture. You cannot customize the selection in the CameraCaptureUI dialog.

For Desktop apps, a list of video capture device monikers can be returned from the device numerator (see [How To Get A List Of Available Video Capture Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258886/how-to-get-a-list-of-available-video-capture-devices) for an example). Then you can plug the desired device moniker in your filter graph via IFilterGraph::AddFilter.